# How do I get the label and input bar to be lower?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
      color: yellow;
      background-color: #1E1B1B;
      }

      .page-root {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 700px;
      }

      .login-box {
      border-radius: 20px;
      background-color: #D8BFD8;
      width: 300px;
      height:350px;
      }
      label[for=fname] {
      color: black;
      margin-top: 500px;
      margin-left: 20px;      
      }
      input[type=text] {
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 2px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="page-root">
      <div class="login-box">
        <form>
          <label for="fname">Email</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above is my code. I am trying to get both the label and input bar to be lower on the `div`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can simply target the form and use `margin-top` on it

```css
form{
  margin-top: 100px; //number depends on how low you want it to be
}
```

another way is to use `top`

```css
form{
  position:relative;
  top: 100px; //number depends on how low you want it to be
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo, your Margin-top is typed "maring-top"

Comment: thanks for catching that. But even fixing the misspelling it didn't change the output.